# Can CoordinatorLayout Behavior be applied only on direct children of CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

Based on my reading so far, `Behavior` can only be applied to direct children of `CoordinatorLayout`. But the following code is confusing me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context=".ScrollingActivity"
            tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:text="@string/large_text" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test Button"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/nestedScrollView"
        app:layout_behavior="am.i.coord.CustomBehavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The `NestedScrollView` is not a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout` (being wrapped in a FrameLayout), but still has a `Behavior` applied, which is properly triggering changes in AppBarLayout.

The `Button` I added at the same level with a custom `behavior` is working only if I make it a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout`. If I move it inside the `FrameLayout` as a sibling of `NestedScrollView`, then none of the callbacks are executed.

Why this difference? **If `Behavior` is not meant to be used by `CoordinatorLayout's` non-direct children, is there another way for the non-direct children to be notified on scroll changes in `NestedScrollView`?** I can only think of adding a dummy view to the `CoordinatorLayout` which will emit scroll events to indirect children, but it makes the code messy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, behaviors must be attached to the direct children of a `CoordinatorLayout`. Why it works for `NestedScrollView` is detailed in the [Intercepting everything with CoordinatorLayout blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/intercepting-everything-with-coordinatorlayout-behaviors-8c6adc140c26#0f70), which states:

> Nested scrolling can originate not only on direct children of a CoordinatorLayout, but on any child View (a child of a child of a child of a CoordinatorLayout, for example)

This is a separate property of nested scrolling itself, not something unique to `CoordinatorLayout`: nested scrolling events propagate up the view hierarchy through each parent `ViewGroup`. This is how `CoordinatorLayout` gains access to those events and Behaviors are what allows `CoordinatorLayout` to dispatch those events to other children not directly in the view hierarchy of the scrolling view.

As you surmised, if you want an indirect child to be aware of scroll changes, you must have a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout`, even if it is a dummy view. You can, of course, create a subclass of `CoordinatorLayout` and hook into the same event stream if you want as [all of the methods](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.java#L1706) can be overridden.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the post, cleared many doubts. My understanding now is that we don't need to apply behavior to a view, unless it depends on some other view. Which makes "app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" on the NestedScrollView almost useless. I tested the appbar with various scrollFlags and collapseMode after dropping the behavior on NestedScrollView. This makes sense because AppBarLayout has defined it's behavior.  Almost all the samples I have come across use this appbar_scrolling_view_behavior. What's the point? Am I missing something by not using it?

Comment: @Jaguar - putting `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` on a nested child isn't doing anything anyways. It needs to be on the direct child (i.e., your `FrameLayout`). As seen in the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.java#1242) it controlls the elevation of the AppBarLayout and also [controls the visible offset](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.java#1388).